# Trigger ALL cloud run instances at once to do async job (rebuild cache)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

I have a cloud run with **multiple instances** running or idle.

I want all the instances to do an async job periodically (to rebuild a cache).

Example of async job:

1. Periodically check if there is a new version of a JSON file on the object storage bucket
2. Do some processing on the JSON and store it as a variable (cache) that will be used by the API endpoints. So I do not need to contact database on each request.

Options on how to do it:

1. **setInterval()** to call rebuildCacheIfNeeded(). Cloud run cannot do async tasks in the background (they are assigned CPU resources only while handling a request).
2. **webcron** will not work. Only one instance would handle the request and the cache would be rebuild only on that instance.
3. **Pub / sub** on new file added to the bucket. **Can pub/sub be setup in the way that all instances are awaken and all will rebuild the cache?** If yes, this would be the best solution.
4. **Call rebuildCacheIfNeeded() on each request** and keep the http connection until the cache is rebuild. I would like to avoid this for obvious reasons.
5. **Kill all instances of cloud run** when new file is added to the bucket. Cloud run should be stateless, so this solution is the only one that complies with statelessness rule. But how kill all instances without running whole redeploy?

Any other possible solutions that I am missing?

Thank you

Please do not suggest "Just use a database"... The cached data is small and I would like to avoid a database latencies and possible point of failure.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use **side-effects** of a service that is neither predictable nor manageable. That will lead to problems today and possibly failure when features are updated or new features are released. Design your application to use documented features.

There is no documented method to achieve your objective.